# Continuous resampling in parallel in Labview

Tags: labview, sampling

I need to resample an arbitrary number of complex signals, perform some miscellaneous operations on them, and finally sum them and save them to a file. The length of the signals forces me to buffer the signals into chunks and operate on them as such.

Most (all that I could find) resampling VIs can operate on chunks, using a reset flag to differentiate between new and appended data. My issue is that I would like to perform resampling on my signals in parallel (or at least interweavingly), which doesn't work as the resample VI keeps its previous state. A way around this would be to resample each signal sequentially, save it to a temporary file and then operate using the new files. This is a poor solution.

Practically, what I need (I think) is to have the resampling VI be cloneable, then I could make an instance for each signal. The VI I am currently using is the "Rational Resample" VI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rational Resampling VI is polymorphic, so you can just select "Multi-Channel instance" to process several channels directly.

Moreover, even a single Rational Resampling VI is defined as "Preallocated clones reentrant execution" (LV2014, 32bit, windows). So if you place several Rational Resampling VIs into several different loops, each of them will maintain its own state (independent on the other instances). They will execute as parallel as LabVIEW execution system allows. Source: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/reentrancy/